# Languages with 0 Number?

Tags: linguistic-typology, grammatical-number, nominals

Languages that conjugate nominals for singular vs. plural number are quite common across the world. Languages which also have a dual conjugation are also fairly common. But is there any language which has a 0-number conjugation: a grammatical number indicating 0 of the specified nominal?

Comment: I assume you mean an affix (not a separate word) which functions in an agreement system on a par with sg/pl.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: This is where negation comes in. Why inflect for zero? Zero is a modern concept. If you already have negation (and all languages do), there's no need. And there are no examples. NPs referring to zero (_nothing, nobody_) are in fact arbitrarily assigned singular number in English.

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile Zero might be a modern concept, but many languages have negative pronouns (e.g., German *kein* or Latin *nullus*) and those are not influenced by modern concepts of zero. Having said this, I am not aware of any language implementing a zero number but I also would not preclude it (imagine a language with multiple obligatory negation both on the subject and the verb: This could be re-analysed as 0-number)

Comment: If there are zero wolves (in the discourse context), then they "do not exist", and are hypothetical. Lushootseed has a "hypothetical" article *kʷi*. Then maybe some language has a "hypothetical" affix, and it could (hypothetically) be included under generalized "number agreement". I am infinitely skeptical that that could happen because I don't think "zero" is cognitively like "1" or "3".